# Implementing a pause button

Tags: ios, objective-c, sprite-kit

I'm new to sprite kit. I'm trying to implement a pause button. i've done this by adding a spriteNode in the scene. When the button is pressed i want a menu to come in the middle of the screen. How can i make such a method?

How can i know if the pause button is pressed? and how can i open a small menu in the middle of the screen?

At the moment i've created a SKSpriteNode which is the pause button and a new scene which contain the pause menu.

To be exactly the pause menu is suppose to be in the foreground of the rest of the game.

i've tried:

```
UIButton *pauseButton = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(40/2, self.frame.size.height-40/2, 40, 40)];
[pauseButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"pause"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[pauseButton addTarget:self action:@selector(pauseMenu:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[self.view addSubview:pauseButton];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest creating the pause menu as another `UIView` which can be added as the subview of the current SKView.

When the pause button is pressed, you can call

```
self.scene.paused = YES;
self.scene.view.paused = YES;
```

**EDIT:** Instead of adding the pause UIButton in the initWithSize: method, add it in the -didMoveToViewMethod:

```
-(void)didMoveToView:(SKView *)view
{
    UIButton *pauseButton = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(40/2, self.frame.size.height-40/2, 40, 40)];
    [pauseButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"pause"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [pauseButton addTarget:self action:@selector(pauseMenu:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [self.view addSubview:pauseButton];

}
```

Comment: i've tried adding a UIButton, but it does not seem to work. nothing is being added to the view?

Comment: At what point in the code are u adding the button to the view?

Comment: at the end of the initWithSize method in my scene

Comment: @akashg - From what I've read, IUButton does not seem to work all that well in SpriteKit. Using a sprite node or label might be the better solution.

Comment: @sangony That is not entirely true. Even though I have created my own subclass for buttons in spritekit, and there are many SpriteKit buttons on GitHub, but considering that the OP wants a button which is on top of the view, I believe a UIButton will work best.

Comment: You should also pause SKView as well. self.scene.view.paused = YES;

Comment: Thanks @AndreyGordeev. Have put so in the answer as well.